# How to get multiple photo uploaded by user in facebook using graph api ? how to get feeling of user?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

How to get multiple photo uploaded by user in facebook using graph api  ? example like user upload 3 photo then right now we get only on.how to get all photo.and how to get feeling like "feeling happy/sad/joyfull".

> me/feed?fields=attachments,full_picture,picture

Comment: what have you tried? have read fb's developer documents ?

Comment: yes,i have tried with this code :me/feed?fields=attachments,full_picture,picture

Comment: @MVCDeveloper Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask